# ExtJs 4 - button's hrefTarget attribute doesn't works

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, extjs4, href

I want make an ExtJs 4 button but the `hredTarget` attribute doesn't work.
This is the button code:

```
tbar:[
            '->',
            {
                xtype:'button',
                text:'Logout',
                iconCls:'logout-icon',
                href:'logout',
                hrefTarget:'_self'
            }
        ]
```

And this is the generated html code:

```
    <div id="button-1026" class="x-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-icon-text-left x-btn-icon-text-left x-btn-default-toolbar-small-icon-text-left" style="margin: 0px; left: 1620px; top: 0px;">
        <em id="button-1026-btnWrap" class="">
            <a id="button-1026-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" role="button" target="_blank" href="logout">
               <span id="button-1026-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner">Salir</span>
               <span id="button-1026-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon logout-icon"></span>
            </a>
         </em>
     </div>
```

Note that in the `a` component the `target` value is `_blank` when should be `_self`. How should I fix this issue?

Comment: Which version of ExtJS 4 are you using?  Seems to be working fine with 4.2.0: http://jsfiddle.net/heC8k/2/

Comment: I'm not very sure, I think it is 4.1. Is this an ExtJs 4.1 Verison?

Comment: You can check your version with Ext.versions.extjs.version

Comment: Thanks. I had ExtJs version 4.0. It seams that this is an issue in that version. I updated ExtJs and now works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams to be an issue on ExtJs 4.0. All works fine after updating the ExtJs version. Thanks everyone.